# Dynamic height calculation of one component and used in another in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a header that is fixed on top and its height varies based on number of additional and expandable rows that it carries. Then i have another `<main>` element that i need to push down equivalent to the height of the `.base` + `.row` elements (and not the `.expandable`). The height can change based on browser window size so it needs to be responsive.

Something like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<main>Some content</main>
```

*Template* of `<app-header>`:

```
<header>
    <section class="base">First row</section>
    <section class="row">Second row</section>
    <section class="expandable">Third row</section>
</header>
```

*Style* of `<app-header>`:

```
header { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }
```

Now header is a separate component in Angular (2/4). What is the best way to approach a solution for this?

P.S: I don't think a CSS solution can work here.

**EDIT**: Made `<app-header>` into a separate component.

Answer (score 3):

```
<header>
    <section #base class="base">First row</section>
    <section #row class="row">Second row</section>
    <section class="expandable">Third row</section>
</header>


<main [ngStyle]="{'margin-top':row.offsetHieght+base.offsetHeight+'px'}">Some content</main>
```

Working : https://plnkr.co/edit/bIisDWSftaFQEEiDHmtT?p=preview

Obviously you can optimise this and make it cleaner by using some reusable functions

This will work too :

```
<main [style.margin-top]="row.offsetHeight+base.offsetHeight+'px'">
  My main content
</main>
```

And this :

```
<main [style.margin-top.px]="row.offsetHeight+base.offsetHeight">
  My main content
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks @milad - Its a good approach. The `.row` items might be more than one. Is there a way to do it without `#row` (local variables) considering `<header>` is going to be a completely separate component from which accessing number of rows which are going to be dynamic might be little hard.

Comment: Please check, I have updated the question to make it more clear :) Thanks!

Comment: For those needing a worked example, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-element-height-whmyyb?file=app/app.component.css as the plunker is broken